# Apply a function to a stream

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

If i have a function f and a stream s . How can I apply this function to the stream. Similiar to how a List.map would work.

It is an infinite stream of any type:

```
type 'a stream = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream)
```

I have come up with this, which is surely wrong but at least it reperesents what i am trying to do

```
type 'a stream = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream) 

let rec map f (cons(x,xsf)) = f x then map f (xsf)
```

Comment: What does your stream look like? A small code fragment would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
module Stream =
    let rec map f (Cons(x,xs)) =
        Cons(f x,fun () -> xs() |> map f)
```

This defines a `Stream` module where we can keep helpful functions for dealing with streams (analogous to the `List` module), with just a single `map` function in it.  The map function takes a function `f` and a stream made by consing `x` to the function `xs`, and maps f over the stream, returning a new stream whose head is `f x` and whose tail is gotten by mapping `f` over the stream that results from calling `xs`.

Comment: Can you ellaboratete on it please? I am an f# noob =)

Comment: @JudithMorales - I've added an explanation.  Let me know if you have other quesions.